# Please explain this ruby code (in rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

Basically question is about ruby syntax

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
      validates :name, presence: true #no error
end
```

[Code Source](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

My 2 Questions

**1**

To me this code `validates :name, presence: true` looks a like call to a method.

How can we call a method inside class body, outside any method? I think its not possible in oops.

**2**

Why I am getting error in  these two variations

```
validates (:name ,  presence: true) #error
```

or

```
validates (:name ,  {presence: true}) #error
```

I have added parentheses to method call, as its allowed in ruby.
First parameter is symbol and 2nd parameter is hash.

In first case I have not added curly braces to hash, as I read that if last parameter is hash you can leave curly braces, In second code I have explicitly added curly braces but still got error.

Can anyone explain this syntax.

Thanks

**Edit 1**

Errors

In first I am getting

*product.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' validates (:name , presence: true) # error ^*

In Second I am getting

*product.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' validates (:title , {presence: true}) # error ^*

Comment: What error do you get? You are aware thet you're using `:name` in the first example, and `:title` in the second. That hasn't got anything to do with it?

Comment: yes, just made the correction

Comment: In first case i am getting this error. "product.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' validates (:name , presence: true) # error ^"

Comment: Ruby is strongly influenced by [Smalltalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk) which is perhaps the quintessential example of object-oriented programming. That you can call methods when defining a class does not take away from this. It's a powerful feature, though one that might seem impossible or strange if coming from a Java or C++ background.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253896/2988

Answer (score 3):

**1:** In ruby you *can* call a method when defining a class:

```
% irb
2.2.2 :001 > class Dummy
2.2.2 :002?>   puts "Making a class..."
2.2.2 :003?>   def hello
2.2.2 :004?>     puts "Hello"
2.2.2 :005?>   end
2.2.2 :006?> end
Making a class...
 => :hello 
2.2.2 :007 > d = Dummy.new
 => #<Dummy:0x000000009ebbf0> 
2.2.2 :008 > d.hello
Hello
 => nil
```

So that's exactly what's going on.

**2:** You get an error because you have a space between the method name and the argument list:

```
% irb
2.2.3 :001 > def func(*splat)
2.2.3 :002?>   puts splat.inspect
2.2.3 :003?> end
 => :func 
2.2.3 :004 > func(:test, :another => :test)
[:test, {:another=>:test}]
 => nil 
2.2.3 :005 > func (:test)
[:test]
 => nil 
2.2.3 :006 > func (:test, :another => :test)
SyntaxError: (irb):6: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
func (:test, :another => :test)
            ^
        from /home/haraldei/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

The second example above, where I'm passing just one arg works because you can enclose any valid expression in parenthesis. This is not the same as an argument list. So the expression:

```
(:test, :another => :test)
```

is not a valid expression, but the parser tries to pass it as one parenthesized argument to the method.

So to summarize, both your argument lists are correct, if you remove the space between them and the function name.

Comment: More specifically: `(:test, { :another => : test })` to make the fact that the second argument is a Hash.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your first question: "Yes it is a method" and this is also somehow the answer to your second question.

The answer to your second question is "remove the space between validates and (". When having `validates (...)` it will throw

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
  validates (:name ,  presence: true)
```

`validates` is a method, and if using parentheses you mustn't use spaces.